# How to update a map with variable as key in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a variable to update the map object but it inserts a new key:value pair. Using task."$key" = value; throws an error.

```js
const task = {
    title : 'update UI for Login',
    description:'update UI for Login',
    status : 'open'
}

const update = (key,value) =>{
  task.key = value;
}

console.log(task);
update('title','Sign Up');
console.log(task);
```

Comment: It should be `task[key] = value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [] to access the key,value pair when accessing an Object by variables

```js
const update = (key,value) => {
  task[key] = value;
}
```